# Resetting a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When the user navigates to a different view and returns back to the original view I would like everything to be reset as though they were coming to the view for the first time.

I was able to stop the audio from playing when they leave, but not an animation method.
how would I be able to do this?

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
        [audioIntro stop];
        [mainAudio stop];
}
```

here's the animation code:

```
- (void) firstAnimation {

        if (playSoundButton.enabled = NO || audioIntro.playing) {
                return;
        }

        UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear;
        myImage.hidden = NO;
        myImage.alpha = 1.0;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:12.0 options:options animations:^ 
        {
            setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES;

                tapImage.alpha = 0.0;

        }

                completion:^(BOOL finished){


        [self performSelector:@selector(secondAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
        }
         ];
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: could you describe what that animation method is?

Comment: it's a simple animation that fades an image in and out. the problem is that when you leave the view and return the image is visible. I tried myImage.hidden = YES; in the viewDidLoad but the image still shows up.

Comment: It would really help if could post the animation code and where you are using it

Comment: ok, I've edited my question above and have added the code. you'll see that firstAnimation calls the method secondAnimation. the secondAnimation code is the same as the first, I didn't post it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a bit hacky - but I would try this:

1. Use the "old style" animation - i.e. not with blocks - use "beginAnimation", setting an animationID for your animation.
2. In you viewWillDisappear method, call "beginAnimation" again, with the *same* animationID, but this time:

   a. Set the animation duration to ZERO
   b. Animate "to" the location where you want the stuff to reset to.
3. Set some sort of kill-flag in the viewWillDisappear method
4. Make the completion function look for the "kill flag" - and *do not* evoke the second animation inside your "secondAnimation" flag if the selector if the "kill flag" is set.

(I am a little unclear - if the "finished" flag would suffice for the "kill-flag" - not having seen your entire code.